# Apache HTTP server has stopped working while installing Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am installing Magento 2. There is no problem till the installation reaches 70% but after that, a popup appears stating **`Apache HTTP server has stopped working`**. It pops up on the screen again and again. Not able to complete the installation process. What should be done?